# How to detect variable change in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to detect when any variable change values and call any function. Function now is not important, i need only to detect if any values is changed. Important think i need to detect every change no only on init.

```
  dagAndDropUser: any;


  onAdd(e) { 
    console.log(' add     ', e.itemData)
    this.dagAndDropUser = e.itemData; // EVERY ADD VARIABLE CHANGE VALUES I NEED TO DETECT IT
    e.toData.splice(e.toIndex, 0, e.itemData); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EventEmitter. For an example:

```js
 dagAndDropUser: any;
 dagAndDropUserValueChanges: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onAdd(e) { 
    console.log(' add     ', e.itemData)
    this.dagAndDropUser = e.itemData; // EVERY ADD VARIABLE CHANGE VALUES I NEED TO DETECT IT
    e.toData.splice(e.toIndex, 0, e.itemData);
    this.dagAndDropUserValueChanges.emit(e.itemData); 
  }
```

Now, if you want to detect value change, you can use:

```js
this.dagAndDropUserValueChanges.subscribe(itemData => {
   console.log('Value Changes: ', itemData);
})
```

Make sure to import `EventEmitter` from `@angular/core`.

**Update:** If you get some error, make sure to change the onAdd method to arrow function method and now you can use the instance of your App Component.

**For an example:**

```js
onAdd = (e) => { 
    console.log(' add     ', e.itemData)
    this.dagAndDropUser = e.itemData; // EVERY ADD VARIABLE CHANGE VALUES I NEED TO DETECT IT
    e.toData.splice(e.toIndex, 0, e.itemData);
    this.dagAndDropUserValueChanges.emit(e.itemData); 
  }
```

After that, you will get some result ("event changes") as you expected.

Comment: Okey but i have I problem here. I using stupid dev extreme for any dag and drop and i have a problem with every this function inside onAdd..Can i to do this without call function inside onAdd? Now error is "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

Comment: Can you provide your full code?

Comment: Yes wait a minute

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: check stackblitz code...only what missing is service but servic is basic put call       return this.http.put<any[]>(`${APP_BASE_API_URL}/Companies/users/${user.id}` , user)}

Comment: Here is probably problem in call this inside add function i posted this question in dev extreme forum.

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t953008/onadd-function-return-bug-when-call-another-function-inside-onadd. question for dx direct

Comment: I can't open the support center, it's a private post. Let me see the stackblitz first.

Comment: I've been update my answer, you can check it out.

Comment: right now no work dag and drop. I can't dag item

Comment: I'm so sorry, I' try before it's working, thats why I give that answer, but after I try again, it's not working. But I've been added ("update") the simple solution for you. You can do it with that solution.

Comment: Hmm no work with fat arrow function. I don't get error only no work dag and drop.

Comment: What happened here friend ??

Comment: what happened here ? :/

Comment: I don't know why your's is not working, by mys, it's working fine. You can check: https://codesandbox.io/s/item-drag-drop-devextreme-list-forked-9u99j

Comment: YES THIS is work. VOTE up for answear...can you explain me what is add = (e) => {}. with fat arrow function ?

Comment: You can Google the full answer, but if I can explain it simply, then if you don't use an arrow function, `this` will only represent the method, but if you use an arrow function, then` this` will represent the class or parent function .

Another thing, the `dxo-item-dragging` component uses` onAdd` as input, not as output. So it's like we gave them a function, that's why there are 2 ways to solve this problem, 1 using the arrow function so we can access our parent class and the second we use bind ("But, it's not working before")